# How to get GeoJSON 'Properties' from PSQL jsonb_build_object?

Tags: postgis, geojson, psql

I'm trying to get a true GeoJSON out of my OpenStreetMap boundaries postgis server [For you: `psql -t -h {base64(MTg1LjIxOS4xMzIuMjE5)} -U boundaries -d boundaries` ]

Building the JSON works:

SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         gid,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::jsonb
) FROM al4 where ST_Intersects( ST_GeomFromText( 'Point(13.404954 52.520008)', 4326 ), al4.geom );

but I don't manage to get the "row" element in the right brackets:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         gid,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::jsonb,
    'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'geom'
) FROM (al4 where ST_Intersects( ST_GeomFromText( 'Point(13.404954 52.520008)', 4326 ), al4.geom )) row;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         gid,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::jsonb,
    'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'geom'
) FROM 
 (SELECT * FROM al4 
   where ST_Intersects( ST_GeomFromText( 'Point(13.404954 52.520008)', 4326 ), al4.geom )
 ) row;
```

Regards